# query a parent child relationship in sql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, inheritance

[image: ER Diagram - Inheritance]

I am working on the above ER diagram. Now an event has complete participation in the child that means an event is either an observation, intervention or a diagnosis but a single event can never exist in more than one child tables.

So event table has:

```
id | event_type

1  | diagnosis
2  | diagnosis
3  | observation
4  | observation
5  | intervention
```

Diagnosis table has:

```
id | name  | event_FK

1  |cancer | 1
2  |none   | 2
```

Observation table has:

```
id|    name            | event_FK

1 |progressive disease | 3
2 |none                | 4
```

I want to run the following query on this model.

"Find all events that have diagnosis.name=cancer and observation.name=progressive disease."

```
The result should contain event id 1 and 3
```

I am trying to do it with joins but can't select only the events which are either of type diagnosis or intervention.I can join the two tables as

```
select * from event e1
left join diagnosis d on d.event_fk = e1.id 
left join observation o on o.event_fk e1.id
```

but this is clearly wrong as the resulting table still has data from 'intervention' table. I need to know how can i eliminate data from this 'intervention' table? also how to write a efficient query for such cases.

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I'm not seeing any kind of `Name` or `Description` or anything on the `Diagnosis` or `Observation` table.  How can you tell if one is `Cancer` or `Progressive Disease`?

Comment: Yes, there is a name column. I have added it to example information.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have done that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `WHERE` clause is executed *after* the `LEFT JOIN`, you can take advantage of that and add a `WHERE` clause to the query filtering out anything that doesn't have those values:

```
Select      E.*
From        Event       E
Left Join   Diagnosis   D   On  D.Event_FK = E.Id
Left Join   Observation O   On  O.Event_FK = E.Id
Where       D.Name = 'Cancer'
Or          O.Name = 'Progressive Disease'
```

> Results:

```
Id  event_type
1   diagnosis
3   observation
```

*Note: Including the right-hand table of a `LEFT JOIN` in the `WHERE` clause typically leads to unexpected results as it essentially transforms the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` by filtering out the `NULL` values.  But in this situation, that's exactly what we want to do.*

Comment: The inner join will not work in this case as after the first inner join, everything is eliminated from the event table except the event_type 'diagnosis'. Hence the second inner join will result in an empty table.

Comment: @rehas Updated the answer.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a complex join to do this without a where clause like a join to alias event table but i guess its fine now that it just works :) Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from event e1
left join diagnosis d on d.event_fk = e1.id 
left join observation o on o.event_fk e1.id where e1.id not in ( select event_fk from Intervention )
```